# How can I use absolute paths in my React styleguidist component library?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, absolute-path, react-styleguidist

I have a React component library that is used in a React app. The component library is setup using Styleguidist and webpack. I've setup webpack to use absolute paths using:

```
webpackConfig: {
  resolve: {
    modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/'), 'node_modules'],
  }
}
```

This works within the context of the component library. When I `build` the component library, the package looks like this:

```
/core
  /components
    /Table
    /Row
```

When I `import` the components into my app, I get an error:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve components/Row in /Users/myusername/Sites/mysite/node_modules/@mypackage/core/components/Table
```

I understand why the paths don't match in the context of `node_modules`, but I would've expected Webpack to transform those import paths during the build process. Is there something I'm missing? Or is this not possible?

Comment: Could you replicate the problem in a GH repo?

Answer (score 0):

While Styleguidist uses webpack, it turns out the build script we were using does not, so the webpack config is irrelevant. Instead, our build script (https://www.npmjs.com/package/cod-scripts) uses babel.

We ended up having to add a separate `babel.config.js` file to define absolute paths for babel using the `babel-plugin-module-resolver` package.

```
npm install babel-plugin-module-resolver --saveDev
npm install @babel/preset-react --saveDev
```

**babel.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    [
      'module-resolver',
      {
        root: ['./src'],
      },
    ],
  ],
  presets: ['@babel/preset-react'],
};
```